# Include the yield inside another function

Tags: python, iterator, generator, yield, coroutine

I have two functions , `generatorA()` calls the `generatorB()` inside it. I want to get all the yield when calling the `generatorB()`, but I only get `0,1,2` 
how to get `0,1,2,3,4,5`

`generatorA()` is a call back function. so I can't say, when It will be called.

```
def generatorA():
    mylist = range(4,6)
    for i in mylist:
        yield i


def generatorB():
    generatorA()

    mylist = range(3)
    for i in mylist:
        yield i

for i in generatorB():
    print(i)
```

Comment: @schwobaseggl I don't know Why they have marked as the duplicate. in my case my function isa call back function

Answer (score 3):

Use `yield from`:

```
def generatorA():
    return range(4,6)  

def generatorB():
    mylist = range(3)
    for i in mylist:
        yield i

    yield from generatorA()

for i in generatorB():
    print(i)
```

**Output**

```
0
1
2
4
5
```

Comment: What if the generator is a call back function .  Than I don't know when it will execute ? Don't we

Answer (score 3):

Use `yield from`, and you can further shorten this with iterable unpacking.

```
def generatorB():
    yield from (*range(3), *generatorA())
```

You could do the same thing to `generatorA`:

```
def generatorA():
    yield from range(4,6)
```

(...But I assume that `generatorA` is a stand-in for something more complex.)

```
>>> list(create())
[0, 1, 2, 4, 5]
```

Comment: what do you mean by * in (*range(3), *generatorA())

Comment: What if the generator is a call back function . Than I don't know when it will execute ? Don't we

Comment: @BalakrishnanSathiyakugan that's the syntax for iterable unpacking. Also, what do you mean by call back in this context and why would it matter?

Comment: I am using keras call back function to get the accuracy and losses for every ephos. so I update it in to the front end using yield and ajax call.

Comment: @BalakrishnanSathiyakugan In that case you might want to look at [`asyncio`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio.html).

Comment: I am doing a web app , when the button is clicked newly updated data will be trained. When the training is on progress, I should show the progress on the the front end. Progress means for every epoch I should show the accuracy and error level. I could easily get it from keras call back functions "on_epoch_end " but the call back has no return method because it's executing only on the model training.